# QGIS set all layers with custom transparency with python?

Tags: qgis, python

I'm exploring QGIS python functions to set all raster layers with a custom transparency, i.e 0,0,0,100 .

Looking at some previous questions. There is a way to loop all the layers, but the aspect to set transparency value on RGB values, I've been having difficulties understanding the documentation.

[How to set the transparency for multiple layers or add a global transparancy preference?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/88908/how-to-set-the-transparency-for-multiple-layers-or-add-a-global-transparancy-pre)

```
for layer in iface.legendInterface().layers():
   layer.renderer().setOpacity(0.2)
```

[How do I set layer transparency in QGIS 2.0 with Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77391/how-do-i-set-layer-transparency-in-qgis-2-0-with-python)
The example here uses TransparentSingleValuePixel but i notice there is a TransparentThreevaluePixel

```
x = QgsRasterTransparency.TransparentSingleValuePixel()
x.pixelValue = 123
x.transparencyPercent = 50
rt.setTransparentSingleValuePixelList( [ x ] )
```

Comment: I don't think I completely understand what you want to do. Do you want to change the raster (source) files or alter the properties of how the layers are displayed? For the latter: why would you want to specify also R, G and B values?

Comment: I think its the way the layers are rendered. Not altering the image file itself.  I have a border of nodata around the image with 0,0,0. It's overlapping on other images. The aim simply to choose the 0,0,0 and set to 100% opacity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use a `QgsRasterTransparency` object then: http://qgis.org/api/2.8/classQgsRasterTransparency.html
(add it to the `renderer()` of the raster layer using `setRasterTransparency()`)

```
r=iface.mapCanvas().layers()[0]
rt=QgsRasterTransparency()
rt.initializeTransparentPixelList(0,0,0)

QgsMessageLog.logMessage(str(rt.transparentThreeValuePixelList()))
# -> [<qgis._core.TransparentThreeValuePixel object at 0x117dab5a8>]

r.renderer().setRasterTransparency(rt)
```

voilà: same result as adding them by hand in the layer properties:

[image: voilà: same result as adding them by hand in the layer properties:]

Comment: to extend on this code here, I apply to this to all layers with the following
`code

for r in iface.mapCanvas().layers():
    rt.QgsRasterTransparency();
    rt.InitializeTransparentPixelList(0,0,0);
    r.renderer().setRasterTransparency(rt);
    r.triggerRepaint();
`