# GIS Action that loads a raster, creates pyramids and sets color

Tags: raster, pyqgis, pyqt, actions

Using the code in ["Developing QGIS Action which loads a raster"](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/225459/developing-qgis-action-which-loads-a-raster).

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QFileInfo,QSettings
from qgis.core import QgsRasterLayer, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem

s = QSettings()
oldValidation = s.value( "/Projections/defaultBehaviour" )
s.setValue( "/Projections/defaultBehaviour", "useGlobal" )
vl = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName('catalogo_CTR')[0]
qgis.utils.iface.setActiveLayer(vl)
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
group_name = "Raster layers"
group = root.findGroup(group_name)
if group == None:
    group = root.addGroup("Raster layers")
else:
    pass
fileName = '\\\\rvphnas02pw\Prodotti_Cartografici\\Ortofoto\\2012_AGEA\\TIFF_GBO\\[% A_CODICE %].tif'
fileInfo = QFileInfo(fileName)
baseName = '[% A_CODICE %]'
rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(fileName, baseName)
crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem()
crs.createFromSrid(3003) 
rlayer.setCrs(crs)
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(rlayer, False)
group.insertChildNode(-1, QgsLayerTreeLayer(rlayer)) 

s.setValue( "/Projections/defaultBehaviour", oldValidation )
```

Is it possible to create automatically the image-pyramids and set color white as trasparent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution using the code in :

-["How to set transparency to multiple raster values with Python"](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/197253/how-to-set-transparency-to-multiple-raster-values-with-python) to set the colors and this

-["How to correctly use gdaladdo in a Python program?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33158526/how-to-correctly-use-gdaladdo-in-a-python-program) to create the pyramids

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QFileInfo,QSettings
from qgis.core import QgsRasterLayer, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem
import gdal
import os
from subprocess import call

#Define gdaladdo
gdaladdoFile = 'C:\\Program Files\\QGIS 2.18\\bin\\gdaladdo.exe'


s = QSettings()
oldValidation = s.value( "/Projections/defaultBehaviour" )
s.setValue( "/Projections/defaultBehaviour", "useProject" )
vl = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName('catalogo_CTR')[0]
qgis.utils.iface.setActiveLayer(vl)
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
group_name = "CTR_10000"
group = root.findGroup(group_name)
if group == None:
    group = root.addGroup("CTR_10000")
else:
    pass
fileName = 'D:\\GIS\\Dati\\IDT_CTRR_Raster\\[% A_CODICE %].tif'
fileInfo = QFileInfo(fileName)
baseName = '[% A_CODICE %]'
rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(fileName, baseName)

call([gdaladdoFile, '-ro', '--config', 'USE_RRD', 'YES', fileName, '2 4 8 16'])

raster_transparency  = rlayer.renderer().rasterTransparency()
ltr = QgsRasterTransparency.TransparentSingleValuePixel()
ltr2 =  QgsRasterTransparency.TransparentSingleValuePixel()
tr_list = []
ltr.min = 0  # Or another value
ltr.max = 0  # Or another value
ltr.percentTransparent = 100  # Or another value
ltr2.min = 8  # Or another value
ltr2.max = 8  # Or another value
ltr2.percentTransparent = 100
tr_list.append(ltr)
tr_list.append(ltr2)

rlayer.triggerRepaint()  # Tried with iface.mapCanvas().refresh(), but it didn't work

raster_transparency.setTransparentSingleValuePixelList(tr_list)
crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem()
crs.createFromSrid(3003) 
rlayer.setCrs(crs)
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(rlayer, False)
group.insertChildNode(-1, QgsLayerTreeLayer(rlayer)) 

s.setValue( "/Projections/defaultBehaviour", oldValidation )
```